# How to get security answer in c# in asp.net membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

```
MembershipUser mu= Membership.GetUser("username");
mu.UserName;
mu.GetPassword();
mu.Email;
mu.PasswordQuestion;
```

i dont find any way to get security answer in code.if there is any way to do it,please give hint..
thanks  in advance...

Answer (score 3):

You can't the Membership API doesn't support retrieving the answer.